# How Dimensional reduction works for document classification

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-mining, svd

with reference to the following link [What does dimensionality reduction mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994431/what-does-dimensionality-reduction-mean), dimensional reduction was well explained with movies and people example
but what I could not understand was how mathematically eigen vectors became the feature's for movies, why eigen vector and not any other vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most vectors carry *some* information in them. So any vector could do that job (and in fact, we often only compute approximate Eigenvectors, because of complexity).

Eigenvectors have the nice property of keeping most of your variance, i.e. the strong Eigenvectors have the most information, whereas the last eigenvectors may be entirely redundant to the earlier ones.

For dimensionality reduction, you want to have as much as possible information in as few as possible vectors. So PCA/SVD is a reasonable choice.

But there are also dimensionality reduction techniques based on *random projections*.

Comment: why the eigen vectors explains the most varience in the matrix

Comment: That is the definition of PCA - projection with maximum variance on first components. See Jolliffe I.T. Principal Component Analysis, Series: Springer Series in Statistics, 2nd ed., Springer, NY, 2002, XXIX, 487 p. 28 illus. ISBN 978-0-387-95442-4